# DetailView iterating reverse ManyToMany objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Given the Django example in making queries:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I'd like to have an author DetailView which contains a list of entries for that author. What I have so far:

```
class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Author

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entries'] = Entry.objects.filter(
            authors__name=self.object.name)
        return context
```

and in my template:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

I'd also prefer to not filter by name but that specific author since name could be non unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `reverse relationship`

```
context['entries'] = self.object.entry_set.all()
```

This gives you all `Entry` objects of that `Author`.

### EDIT:

And why are you using `author__name`?
You can filter by the object directly:

```
context['entries'] = Entry.objects.filter(authors=self.object)
```

Comment: author__name wasn't what I originally had though I added it when experimenting with various queries. Both your suggestions work wonderfullly though I had to change the first since I had a related_name. Thank you. Do you know if there is any performance difference between the two or if one is preferable?